# How can I disable the Employee Timecard (EP406000) 'update' button

Tags: acumatica

I've been able to disable the insert and delete buttons on the Employee Timecards screem (EP406000) - but the update button doesn't seem to care.  Here's my code:

```
    protected void TimecardFilter_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Base.create.SetEnabled(false);
        Base.update.SetEnabled(false);
        Base.delete.SetEnabled(false);
    }
```

It works for the insert and delete - but not for the update.  I noticed in the source code that the code for the update button is a little different in that it doesn't have a [PXUIField] attribute, along with a few others.  The insert and delete buttons have a similar setup and attributes, but update is definitely different.  Not sure if this is why.

Bottom line:  How can I disable the update button on the Employee Timecard (EP406000) screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagnostic that the Update action is missing the PXUIField attribute is spot on.

Some button properties functionality requires having a PXUIField attribute.:
[image]

You can redefine the Update action to add the PXUIField attribute:

```
using PX.Data;

namespace PX.Objects.EP
{
    public class TimecardPrimary_Extension : PXGraphExtension<TimecardPrimary>
    {
        public PXAction<TimecardPrimary.TimecardFilter> update;

        [PXButton(Tooltip = Messages.EditTimecardToolTip, ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.RecordEdit)]
        [PXUIField]
        protected virtual void Update()
        {
            EPTimeCard row = PXSelect<EPTimeCard, Where<EPTimeCard.timeCardCD, Equal<Current<TimecardWithTotals.timeCardCD>>>>.Select(Base);
            if (row == null) return;

            PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(Base, row, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.InlineWindow);
        }

        protected void TimecardFilter_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            Base.create.SetEnabled(false);
            Base.update.SetEnabled(false);
            Base.delete.SetEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the PXUIField attribute will make the SetEnabled method work:
[image]

If you double-click on a grid record it will invoke the Grid default action (update in this case).
When double-clicking the record it will notify the user that the action is disabled:
[image]

To prevent invoking a disabled default action, you can customize the grid action bar to remove the default action:
[image]

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated!